# MySQL LIKE query not pulling similar data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL-based search script, I will post only the part relevant to the problem below.

```
$name = 'John Doe';
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE %$name%';
```

Now, the problem is when I search for `John Doe` instead of getting the user with that particular name, I get all users named `John` and `Doe` and, the funny thing is that, it does not even put `John Doe` at the top, meaning... you could find `John xxxx` before that.

Is there and advanced MySQL attribute to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE %$name%';
```

to

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE "'.%$name%.'"';
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
```

note, that changing to

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE "%$name%"';
```

will *NOT* do the trick.

This is because [single quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) do not interpret variables.

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

[Double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) however, will.

> The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details.

UPDATE:
This was heavily edited and changed in meaning, thanks to Memolition :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE %$name%';
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
```

not

```
$query = 'SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE "%$name%"';
```

because the double quotes as luksch says will print $name instead of $name variable value

so it has to be single quotes `'` like this `'%name'`

so `'` single quotes works for `strings` and `variables`

and `"` double quotes only works for `strings`

Comment: you copy paste the prior answer? I mean, please edit the prior answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have single quotes around your the string you are using as the comparison for `LIKE`

In fact, since you have your query in single quotes what you are really querying against is:

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE %$name%
```

with literal `$name`.

Write your query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM members WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Full Text index(only MyISAM AFAIR) and MATCH AGAINST clause.
It will also give you rate of similarity. Very useful in some cases.
Examples here: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9182/mysql-full-text-searching-match-against/p1